# Not able to use OAuth 2.0 to access Google Analytics API GA4

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to set up access to Google Analytics data using Google OAuth 2.0 sign-in (instead of a service account). However, I can't find documentation or examples on how to do it with JS.

The Oauth authentication is working and I get both an access and refresh token. Then I tried to access the Google Analytics API with it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-analytics/data

The error I get from below is 'Error: Could not load the default credentials'. What I am missing is how *analyticsDataClient* can use the auth *oauth2Client*

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const tokens = { access_token: event.queryStringParameters.accessToken, refresh_token: event.queryStringParameters.refreshToken }

oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens)

const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient()

  const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
    property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: '7daysAgo',
        endDate: 'today',
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        name: 'activeUsers',
      },
    ],
  });
```

PS: I'm a junior dev